# Conditional operations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I would like to do some operations between columns that meet some criteria.

For example, I have the following table:

[image]

What I am interested in, is to deduct every column that has for `Mar = P` from every column that has `Mar = I` but the same `Type`

It the end, I would like the following:

**Note:** The values are just indicative.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am little confused.  Your results show LCX as a subtraction of I - P but your values show 4 = 4 - 4 shouldn't LCX be 1,0,0,0 instead of 1,2,3,4?

Comment: You are correct, I copied/pasted the columns and just changed the names, but not the values, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood the question, this seems to be a simple case of masking.

```
dict = {'Size':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Com':['P', 'G', 'P', 'G'], 'Mar':['I', 'P', 'I', 'P'], 'Type':['Lambda1', 'Lambda2', 'Lambda1', 'Lambda2'],'0':[1,2,3,4], '1':[2,2,2,2],'2':[3,3,3,3,], '3':[4,4,4,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
#To get Lambda1 & 'I'
df[(df['Type']=='Lambda1') & (df['Mar']=='I')].T

#To get Lambda2 & 'P'
df[(df['Type']=='Lambda2') & (df['Mar']=='P')].T
```

Comment: I get a KeyError: 'Type'

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Size':[*'ABCDEF'],'Com':[*'PGPGPG'], 'Mar':[*'IPIPEA'],
                   '0':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   '1':[2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   '2':[3,3,3,3,3,3],
                   '3':[4,4,4,4,4,4],
                   'Type':['Lamba1']*2+['Lamba2']*2+['Lamba1']*2})

df1 = df.set_index(['Size','Com','Mar','Type']).T
print(df1)
```

Input Dataframe Output:

```
Size      A      B      C      D      E      F
Com       P      G      P      G      P      G
Mar       I      P      I      P      E      A
Type Lamba1 Lamba1 Lamba2 Lamba2 Lamba1 Lamba1
0         1      2      3      4      5      6
1         2      2      2      2      2      2
2         3      3      3      3      3      3
3         4      4      4      4      4      4
```

Use `pd.IndexSlice` and `groupby`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df_out = df1.loc[:,idx[:,:,'I':'P',:]].T.groupby('Type').diff().dropna().T.rename({'B':'L','D':'L','G':'C','P':'X'}, axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output Results:

```
Size      L       
Com       C       
Mar       X       
Type Lamba1 Lamba2
0       1.0    1.0
1       0.0    0.0
2       0.0    0.0
3       0.0    0.0
```